# What is the easiest way to validate date duration from two DateTimePicker in C#.net?

Tags: c#

So I have this program for assigning people to projects. In my database I already have some samples projects with assigned employees. I have to be able to cross match my current project's start and end date to the projects that the employee is assigned too.

I can't do it like

```
if (this_StartDate == assignedProj_StartDate || this_EndDate == assignedProj_EndDate)
```

because that would only match the exact dates.

I need to be able to mark the employee available if this_StartDate & this_EndDate is not within the period of the assigned project to him. Help?

Comment: Duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786821/check-if-a-date-range-is-within-a-date-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to check whether the the `this` range is outside of the `assignedProj` range:

```
if (this_StartDate > assignedProj_EndDate 
 || this_EndDate < assignedProj_StartDate)
```

This assumes that both ranges are valid (end > start)

Answer (score 0):

the  >  and <  signs might be useful to you