# Checking if 2 dates passes the range of other 2 dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I have a WebApplication that manages events into tables like an Agenda..
For each event I have a **StartDate** and **EndDate**.

In the Application I want to export the events into a graph, and I want to check if the event passes the range of the required dates.

For example:
Event 1: StartDate (9 September) EndDate (14 September)

I want to check if it passes (10 Sept - 16 Sept)

This is a photo of the events example Graph:
[image]

This is a code that checks for only one date:

```
public static bool Within(this DateTime current, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        return startTime < currentTime < endTime;
    }
```

**Edit:**
To clarify more, I want the function to return true if the event passes the 2 dates range,
even if it start before the range or ends after the rang it should return true anyway.

only return false if it does not pass the range.

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786821/check-if-a-date-range-is-within-a-date-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer this way:

```
public static bool Within(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, DateTime StartRange, DateTime EndRange)
    {
        if ((StartDate == EndDate) && (StartRange <= StartDate && StartDate <= EndRange))
            return true;
        else
            return ((StartRange >= StartDate && StartRange <= EndDate) || (EndRange >= StartDate && EndRange <= EndDate));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool Within(DateTime one, DateTime two,
                          DateTime lowBound, DateTime highBound)
{
    return one >= lowBound && two <= highBound;
}
```

Comment: Within(new DateTime(2013, 9, 9), new DateTime(2013, 9, 14), new DateTime(2013, 9, 10), new DateTime(2013, 9, 16));

Returned False

Comment: @AnasNaim that's right, because 09/09 is not inside the 09/10 (day/month).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool Within(this DateTime current, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        return startTime < currentTime && currentTime < endTime;
    }
```

And call it twice

```
lowDate.Within(eventStart, eventEnd) && heDate.Within(eventStart, eventEnd)
```