# Calculating overlapping dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a collection of event dates which consist of the following:

```
class EventDate
{
    DateTime startDate;  // the date when the event starts
    int lengthInHours;   // how many hours the event will run for
}
```

When a new one is to be added, I need to check to make sure the event will not overlap any of the existing events in the collection.

What would be an elegant way to do this check?

Comment: The collection which is holding the objects of this class should have this validation implemented.

Comment: Can you show your code that contains collection of event dates ?

Comment: Please refer this question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786821/check-if-a-date-range-is-within-a-date-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **TimePeriodChain** class of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET). The collection ensures chaining time periods:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void TimePeriodChainSample()
{
  TimePeriodChain timePeriods = new TimePeriodChain();

  DateTime now = ClockProxy.Clock.Now;
  DateTime testDay = new DateTime( 2010, 7, 23 );

  // --- add ---
  timePeriods.Add( new TimeBlock(
                   TimeTrim.Hour( testDay, 8 ), Duration.Hours( 2 ) ) );
  timePeriods.Add( new TimeBlock( now, Duration.Hours( 1, 30 ) ) );
  timePeriods.Add( new TimeBlock( now, Duration.Hour ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "TimePeriodChain.Add(): " + timePeriods );
  // > TimePeriodChain.Add(): Count = 3; 23.07.2010 08:00:00 - 12:30:00 | 0.04:30
  foreach ( ITimePeriod timePeriod in timePeriods )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Item: " + timePeriod );
  }
  // > Item: 23.07.2010 08:00:00 - 10:00:00 | 02:00:00
  // > Item: 23.07.2010 10:00:00 - 11:30:00 | 01:30:00
  // > Item: 23.07.2010 11:30:00 - 12:30:00 | 01:00:00

  // --- insert ---
  timePeriods.Insert( 2, new TimeBlock( now, Duration.Minutes( 45 ) ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "TimePeriodChain.Insert(): " + timePeriods );
  // > TimePeriodChain.Insert(): Count = 4; 23.07.2010 08:00:00 - 13:15:00 | 0.05:15
  foreach ( ITimePeriod timePeriod in timePeriods )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Item: " + timePeriod );
  }
  // > Item: 23.07.2010 08:00:00 - 10:00:00 | 02:00:00
  // > Item: 23.07.2010 10:00:00 - 11:30:00 | 01:30:00
  // > Item: 23.07.2010 11:30:00 - 12:15:00 | 00:45:00
  // > Item: 23.07.2010 12:15:00 - 13:15:00 | 01:00:00
} // TimePeriodChainSample
```

Comment: Sweet.  Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

```
class EventDate
{
    DateTime startDate;  // the date when the event starts
    int lengthInHours;   // how many hours the event will run for

    public bool Overlaps(EventDate otherDate)
    {
        double hours = (otherDate.startDate - startDate).TotalHours;
        return (hours >= 0 && hours <= lengthInHours) ||
               (hours < 0 && -hours <= otherDate.lengthInHours);
    }
}
```

Usage for collection:

```
bool isOverlapped = collection.Any(date => date.Overlaps(newDate));
```