# How to check if a selected date range is within a date range

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I'm trying to check if a selected dates range by the user is within a range of dates exist in database.

e.g.

User select :

**Start date : 24/09/2022**

**End date : 30/09/2022**

Date range in database is :

**Start date : 28/09/2022**

**End date : 30/09/2022**

Imagine you have a reservation car between 28/09 → 30/09, if a user wants to reserve this car between 24/09 --> 30/09, then the app should notify them that the car is reserved in that date because it's already reserved between 28--> 30.

My situation is similar to this: [Check if a date range is within a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786821/check-if-a-date-range-is-within-a-date-range). Only that question is about C#, and I am coding Java.

My code so far :

```
   boolean isFound = DateHelper.isWithinRange2Dates(
                /*ENTERED BY USER*/
                string2Date("24/09/2022"),
                string2Date("30/09/2022"),
                /*IN DATABASE*/
                string2Date("28/09/2022"),
                string2Date("30/09/2022"));

        ToastUtils.showLong(isFound ? "FOUND" : "NOT FOUND");
```

Methods used :

```
   public static boolean isWithinRange(Date selectedDate, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        return selectedDate.after(startDate) && (selectedDate.before(endDate) || DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDate, endDate));
    }
    
   public static boolean isWithinRange2Dates(Date selectedStartDate, Date selectedEndDate, Date startDate, Date  endDate) {
        return isWithinRange(selectedStartDate, startDate, endDate) && isWithinRange(selectedEndDate, startDate, endDate);
    }



@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public static Date string2Date(String dateStr) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Issue:**

**28/09 --> 30/09** is within the **24/09 --> 30/09** so the method should true

**Question:**

How I can check if a selected start and end date are within a date range or not?

Comment: Inclusive? Are 28–29/9 and 29–30/9 both within 28–30/9?

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Massive thanks for your help guys, @OleV.V. my apologies I didn't include the `string2Date` method

Comment: @OleV.V. please check my updated post

Comment: Does the below answer worked for you?

Comment: `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: I seem to get from your comments (that I also pasted into your question) that you want to decline the reservation if there is *an overlap* between the two intervals in question. If the car is already reserved 27–29/9 and the user wants to book it 28–30/9, it should be declined, am I right? Is your situation really more similar to this one? [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: You are really making it unnecessarily complicated for yourself and for us by using the poorly designed and obsolete `Date` class. Now I get *DateUtils cannot be resolved* at `DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDate, endDate)`. I was curious to debug your code and discover what went wrong, but I am giving up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your isWithin range functions operator
Precedence is wrong.Also checking isSameDate for both end and start dates are missing. In your code it return false if user startDate is simmilar to your dateRange start date or  if user end date simmilar to datarange end date. Correct implementation as follows of isWithinRange function.

```
return (selectedDate.after(startDate) || DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDate, startDate)) && (selectedDate.before(endDate) || DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDate, endDate));
```

Use || operator not && for isWithinRange2Dates function as follows.

```
return isWithinRange(selectedStartDate, startDate, endDate) || isWithinRange(selectedEndDate, startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but unfortunately, it does not work

Comment: If  the user date range and db date range same what should return?

Comment: now check it should work

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the issue here is I need to check if date range **(selectedStartDate-->SelectedEndDate)** is within the **(startDate-->EndDate)** and vice versa for example 28/09 --> 30/09 is within the 24/09 --> 30/09 so the method should return true

Comment: in your code I can see you are adding db date range before selected date range. It not match with your explaination.I confused about it mate.

Comment: Imagine you have a reservation car between 28/09 → 30/09, if a user want to reserve this car between 24/09 --> 30/09 then the app should notify them that the car is reserved in that date because it's already reserved between 28--> 30, I hope I made my question clear, and thank you again for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248326/discussion-between-yjr-and-mouaad-abdelghafour-aitali).

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange.of
(
    LocalDate.of( … ) ,
    LocalDate.of( … )
) 
.encloses
(
    LocalDateRange.of
    (
        startJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate() ,
        stopJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate()
    ) 
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

One of the many design flaws in the `Date` class is that there are actually *two* `Date` classes:

- `java.util.Date`
- `java.sql.Date`

The first represents a moment as seen in UTC. The second *pretends* to represent a date-only, without a time-of-day and without an offset or time zone. But actually, in a case of *extremely* poor judgement, the second class extends from the first… so it does indeed internally represent a moment in UTC. Messy? Yes, a terrible mess.

## `LocalDate`

You neglect to mention in your Question which class you are using. So I'll go with the second one, `java.sql.Date`.

When handed a `java.sql.Date` object, immediately convert to the modern replacement: [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html). Do so by calling the [new conversion method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate()) added to the old class.

```
LocalDate ld = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate() ;
```

## `LocalDateRange`

To compare date ranges, you *could* write the code yourself. But why bother? Add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. Doing so gives you access to the [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class. That class provides several handy methods such as `contains`, `abuts`, `encloses`, `overlaps`, etc.

```
LocalDateRange target = 
    LocalDateRange.of(
        LocalDate.of( … ) ,
        LocalDate.of( … )
    ) 
;
```

… and:

```
LocalDateRange selected = 
    LocalDateRange.of(
        startJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate() ,
        stopJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate()
    ) 
;
```

Compare.

```
boolean enclosed = target.encloses( selected ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer my question